# Rails modeling help, association and logic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am a junior developer who just took first rails project. There are many hurdles I am facing but learning a lot from doing. So far I was able to figure out the multiple users in [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) and all that good stuff. But semi confident with authorization. Still learning as I go and am confident I will figure it out.

But the only Brick wall moment I am having for past week is to modeling my app for order part. Here is a little summary of app i am working on:

1. Its B2B
2. User types are Retailer and Supplier
3. Retailer places an order with the supplier
4. There is just one product with 3 different types or more, product_type1, product_type2, product_type3
5. supplier Updates the price for the product types every day and retailer sees the current price in their dashboard
6. Supplier also has formula for each product prices for each individual retailers.

For eg, his base price + margin, his margin is different for each retailer.

So how do I model this? I want retailer to place an order to the supplier with their respective price.

What do I need?

Product model? With price and type?

Separate formula model?

Comment: Take some time and finish the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) from beginning to end and execute all the examples given.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'd highly recommend reading http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ and http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html. Also, programmers spend a lot of time researching and trying before asking; A *LOT* of time. We expect that of our peers; http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand your feeling, since I had exactly this problem before, let me share what I did, hope it helps solve your problem:

`User` model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # A user is a registered person in our system
  # Maybe he has 1/many retailers or suppliers
  has_many :retailers
  has_many :suppliers
end
```

`Order` model:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  # An order was placed for supplier by retailer
  belongs_to :retailer
  belongs_to :supplier
  # An order may have so many products, we use product_capture
  # because the product price will be changed frequently
  # product_capture is the product with captured price
  # at the moment an order was placed
  has_many :product_captures
end
```

`Product` model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :retailer
  has_many :product_captures
  # Custom type for the product which is not in type 1, 2, 3
  enum types: [:type_1, :type_2, :type_3, :custom]
end
```

`ProductCapture` model:

```
class ProductCapture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  attr_accessible :base_price, :margin

  def price
    price + margin
  end
end
```

`....other models`

So the idea is:

1. A user may have many retailers or suppliers (Verify requirement for this, I'm not sure this is correct or not in your case)
2. We always create an order for retailer and supplier with the latest product capture of product, this ensures the latest price will be applied
3. When retailer updates their price (base price + margin), we create a new `ProductCapture` which becomes the latest one, all old captures still are in the database because old orders are still using it.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what i needed. Thank you for taking your time explaining it. Also the supplier updates the price for retailer.